# How to prove that some diffeomorphism preserves area?

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to know if there is a method in general, given two regular surfaces and a diffeomorphism f between the two, to prove that $f$ preserves areas, if f is not an isometry

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should learn the basics of MathJax so that we can actually read your posts. At any rate, my suggestion would be to pull back the area $2$-form $\sigma$ of the codomain by the mapping $f$ and see if it gives the area $2$-form of your domain. In the case of your $P$, we have $\sigma = dx\wedge dy$. Is $f^*(dx\wedge dy) = dx\wedge dy$?

Comment: This'll be true iff the Jacobian determinant, $|\operatorname{det}f'|=1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Thank you

Comment: The Jacobian is the determinant of the matrix of partials.

Comment: Sorry I was asking about the proposition with the iff det=1 , I didn't see that in class so I don't think I could use it on the final. What would you do to prove it in general? (If it was true that an f preserves areas between two regular surfaces) considering that the content of dif geometry in my course is very basic (we use Do Carmo)

Comment: This is the change of variables theorem.  It is sort of a prerequisite for do Carmo, I think.  See Buck's _Advanced Calculus_.  As @TedShifrin points out, this is an example of a _pullback_ of an n-form, or $2$- form in this case

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jacobian is in this case $|2+\cos y|$.  Thus $f$ is not area preserving.